# When data gets updated everything duplicates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem I am having is, that every time user gets updated or a new user appears, allusers get duplicated data, I guess let y = [] holds everything, and when an update happens pushes all data on top again.
How would I have all users state hold all users in one array and when something changes it would not duplicate?

```js
const getUsers = async () => {
    let y = [];
    return await firestore.collection("users").onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const x = Object.assign(doc.data(), { userId: doc.id });
        y.push(x);
      });
      setAllUsers(y);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Console inside forEach and just check if x is being generated and pushed twice?

Comment: Just did that, x does not duplicate.

Comment: *"I guess let y = [] holds everything"* - I would guess that `let y = []` sets `y` to an empty array.  Have you debugged to validate your guess?  Just before calling `setAllUsers(y)` output the value of `y` to the console.  Does it contain duplicates?

Comment: Yes, it does get contain duplicates. But when i console x i always get same number of data returned, so I assume y.push(x) is a problem, how to fix it i don't know. or perhaps there is another way, o give all the data to state.

Comment: @Lygis: If `y.push(x)` pushes duplicates to the array then you'll need to check for the value in the array before pushing the new value to the array.  Or perhaps filter the array after pushing all of the values.  Something like: `setAllUsers(y.filter(/* filter logic */));`